# How to get cursor position in 2.8

Tags: python, 3d-cursor

So I'm trying to convert the following [script](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/76303/how-to-use-script-get-event-3d-cursorposition-change-in-blender) in 2.8

I have replaced scene with depsgraph.

But I'm getting an erroneous on last line:
Scene object has no attribute 'cursor.location'

```
import bpy
from mathutils import Vector

#A class that takes into account a context and one of its attributes value
#If the value changes a callback is fired
class EventWatcher:

    #Set of watchers
    eventWatchers = set()

    @staticmethod
    def AddWatcher( watcher ):
        EventWatcher.eventWatchers.add( watcher )    

    @staticmethod
    def RemoveWatcher( watcher ):
        EventWatcher.eventWatchers.remove( watcher )

    @staticmethod
    def RemoveAllWatchers():
        EventWatcher.eventWatchers.clear()

    #From 'context', 'path' needs to exist
    #'comparer' is to compare the previous value of context.path to its new value
    #'callback' is the cb called if the value if changed
    #'copyValue' indicates if the value needs to be copied (that can be needed as if not old and new value may point onto the same object)
    def __init__( self, context, path, comparer, callback, copyValue ):
        self.context = context
        self.path = path
        self.comparer = comparer
        self.callback = callback
        self.copyValue = copyValue
        self.currentValue = self.GetValue()

    def GetValue( self ):
        value = getattr( self.context, self.path )
        if self.copyValue:
            value = value.copy()
        return value

    def Fire( self ):
        newValue = self.GetValue()
        if self.comparer( self.currentValue, newValue ) == False:
            self.callback( self, newValue )
            self.currentValue = newValue

#Global loop on the watchers. This callback responds to scene_update_post global handler
def cb_scene_update(context):
    for ew in EventWatcher.eventWatchers:
        ew.Fire()

#To stop the calls at the scene_update_post event level
class StopCallback(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "scene.stop_callback"
    bl_label = "Stop Callback"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return cb_scene_update in bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post

    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.app.handlers.scene_depsgraph_post.remove(cb_scene_update)
        return {'FINISHED'}

#To start the calls at the scene_update_post event level
class StartCallback(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "scene.start_callback"
    bl_label = "Start Callback"

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return cb_scene_update not in bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post

    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.app.handlers.depsgraph_update_post.append(cb_scene_update)
        return {'FINISHED'}

#The panel is located in the scene properties
class SceneEventsPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Scene events"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_scene_events"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "scene"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("scene.start_callback")
        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("scene.stop_callback")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SceneEventsPanel)
    bpy.utils.register_class(StartCallback)
    bpy.utils.register_class(StopCallback)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SceneEventsPanel)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(StartCallback)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(StopCallback)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    register()


print( '--------' )

#Example:

#The comparaison (for cursor location, it is a vector comparison)
def CompareLocation( l1, l2 ):
    return l1 == l2

#The callback to execute when the cursor's location changes    
def CompareLocationCallback( watcher, newValue ):
    print( 'New value', newValue )

#Install the watcher which will run the callback
EventWatcher.AddWatcher( EventWatcher( bpy.data.scenes[0], "cursor.location", CompareLocation, CompareLocationCallback, True ) )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it is not the last line that is causing the error but the `GetValue` method.

In order to access the `location` attribute of the `cursor` attribute of the scene, you must execute `scene.cursor.location`. Meaning you must first get access to the cursor, then to its location. What you can do is replace your `GetValue`method with :

```
def GetValue( self ):
    split_path = self.path.split(".")
    attr_path = split_path[0]
    if not hasattr(self.context, attr_path):
        print(f"Error : {self.context} does not have any attribute named {attr_path}")
        return None
    value = getattr(self.context, split_path[0])  # Access 1st member of the property path
    for depth in range(len(split_path[1::])):  # Iteratively access the other members
        attr_path = split_path[depth + 1]
        if not hasattr(value, attr_path):                
            print(f"Error : {value} does not have any attribute named {attr_path}")
            break
        value = getattr(value, attr_path)
    if self.copyValue and hasattr(value, "copy"):
        value = value.copy()
    return value
```

Meaning, if you want to access the X coordinate of the cursor location, you can change the last line to :

```
EventWatcher.AddWatcher(EventWatcher(bpy.data.scenes[0], "cursor.location.x", CompareLocation, CompareLocationCallback, True))
```

Result :

[image]

By the way, I suggest looking at the [guidelines for python](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_best_practice.html) naming and such in Blender.

Comment: thank you so much. How can I add a cube in those locations, pe each click?

Comment: Glad it helped. :) I can answer your other question but it is outside the scope of this one, would you mind adding it as another question and then linking it in the comments ?